# Global helper functions in doT.js templating

Tags: javascript, template-engine, dot.js

I want to define and use a global helper function for the **doT.js template engine** how can I do this?

What I want to do is is something like this.

```
var xyz = function(p1, p2) { return p1 + p2; }
```

And use it in a doT.js template like this:

```
{{xyz(2,5)}}
```

Comment: @Connor if you declare your xyz as global with `window.xyz = function(p1, p2) { return p1 + p2; }` it should work in your template like in the example: `{{= xyz(2,5)}}` http://jsfiddle.net/52EXA/

Comment: @nemesv that's interesting to know, does it work for node? This bounty expires soon and there will be no answers, better yours than none aye?

Comment: @Connor I haven't tried it with node, but I guess you can do there the same but use the `global` object instead of the `window` so `global.xyz = function(p1, p2) { return p1 + p2; }` altough this pollutes your global namespace, however if you want to have a real global helper you need to make it really global

Comment: @nemesv doesn't doT prefix everything with `it`?

Comment: @Connor no, you only need the `it` to access the currently passed in data object. But leaving the `it` out you can access any global object/function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so by using some of the advanced features of doT.js, see their [advanced snippets examples](https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/master/examples/advancedsnippet.txt) for other advanced use.

This is how to defined a function to be used

```
{{##def.fntest = function() {
    return "Function test worked!";
}
#}}
```

And this execute it.

```
{{#def.fntest()}}
```